# How to 'count' number of non-empty values in a single row across multiple columns in a dataframe

Tags: r, count, na

I have a data frame that is similar as follows:

```
Comp1  Comp2  Comp3  Comp4
0.5      0.4    na     0.6
0.6      na     na      0.7
na       0.4    na      1.1
```

Each row represents a different person. For each person I want to calculate how many non-empty values they have in that specific row across those columns and save this as a new variable

thanks !

Comment: Try `rowSums(df != 'na')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about missing values in `R`, it's represented in capital letter `NA` instead of `na`, otherwise, `R` will treat it as a string, which is not empty.

Also, I have artificially included some `Name` in your `df` to act like each row represents one `Name`, and a artificial `Comp5` which includes some `NA`s but will not be included in the calculation.

`rowSums()` as its name suggests, calculates the sum of the row.
`is.na(df[, 2:4])` makes it only counts the `NA` in `df` from column 2 to column 4.

```
df <-read.table(header = T, 
                text = 
                  "Name Comp1  Comp2  Comp3  Comp4  Comp5
                A 0.5      0.4    NA     0.6  NA
                B 0.6      NA     NA      0.7 1
                C NA       0.4    NA      1.1 NA")

df$Count_NA <- rowSums(is.na(df[, 2:4]))
```

### Output

```
  Name Comp1 Comp2 Comp3 Comp4 Comp5 Count_NA
1    A   0.5   0.4    NA   0.6    NA        1
2    B   0.6    NA    NA   0.7     1        2
3    C    NA   0.4    NA   1.1    NA        2
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Only problem is I don't want to calculate sums of the entire row in the data frame (as some data is participant information). I only want to perform this over specific variables - If you can please advise? :)

Comment: See my edited answer.